# sending email from microsoft exchange account using matlab

Tags: matlab

Has anyone figured out a way to use matlab to send email from a corporate microsoft exchange account **w/o using activex**?  I found a solution that uses [activex here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/7a46ec9fb1ac2a35?hide_quotes=no&fwc=1&pli=1), but unfortunately I don't have outlook installed on the machine that I want to send emails from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the corporate MS Exchange server and your matlab computer/server are on the same network/subnet. Like all email servers, MS Exchange supports SMTP protocol. You should be able to sending using standard SMTP libraries. I googled and found this simple example

http://www.amirwatad.com/blog/archives/2009/01/31/sending-emails-with-matlab/

Only issue I can see you running into is that the exchange server might now be open to relaying messages. Two options in that case are, determine if you need to authenticate, or ask for the exchange admin to provide your matlab computer/server with a "open relay connector" just for your computer (which further means you probably will have to have a static IP on that matlab computer).

Comment: I've already tried this.  It says: Could not connect to SMTP host: mycorphostname, port: 25; Connection refused: connect.  I'm guessing this means the server is not open to relaying?

Comment: did you try that from a manual telnet session? or was that message returned by the matlab SMTP functions? To get a better idea, could yuo post what you see when you type "telnet mycorphostname 25" from a command prompt?

Comment: I discovered that I needed a special smtp hostname in order to do it in my corporate environment.  The server my outlook is connected to does not allow this functionality.